# DRF, send help text of model field

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

For instance,

```
 shipping_required = models.BooleanField(
     pgettext_lazy('ProductVariant field', 'shipping required'),
     default=True
 )
```

When I send over `shipping_required` field, I'd like to send over `pgettext_lazy('ProductVariant field', 'shipping required')` as well as a first step to make our app internationalized.

Would there be a convenient way to do it with DRF?

Answer (score 0):

This is not help text. this is verbose name field.

You can get verbose_name from Model's Meta Field.

```
# ModelSerializer method
def get_<field_name>(self, obj):
    meta = [f for f in obj._meta.fields if f.name == '<meta>']
    return {
        'verbose_name': meta[0].verbose_name.title(),
        'value': obj.<field_name>
    }
```